# Overall Percentage of Helpful Flags

Tags: feature-request, flag-history, helpful-flags

When viewing **your own** flag history, I feel it would be valuable to show what ***percentage*** of flags have been marked as *helpful*.

I've implemented this as a userscript but would like to make a formal feature-request.

This is the result I came up with:

[image: Overall Helpful Flag Percentage]

Feature Request ***Ideas***

- Change the percentage color based on some sort of grading scale (90%, 80%, 70%)
- Display a warning when users are approaching a dangerous threshold
- Display the percentage as a progress bar
- Show a unicorn for 100% helpful users (*I'm kidding...maybe?*)

---

### The UserScript

This script does not count pending, aged away and [disputed flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/307724).

I did not include the disputed flags in the total for the following reason:

> A disputed flag is whenever your flag was dismissed as neither helpful
>   or declined, someone reviewed your flag but no conclusive action was
>   taken

Here is the userscript for those who are interested. Feel free to change whatever you like.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Helpful Flag Percentage
// @namespace    https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454538/
// @author       enki
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/users/flag-summary/*
// ==/UserScript==
/*jslint browser: true, white: true*/
/*jslint this */
/*global $, jQuery*/
$(function () {
'use strict';

    var helpfulFlags = 0;
    $("td > a:contains('helpful')").parent().prev().each(function () {
        helpfulFlags += parseInt($(this).text().replace(",",""));
    });

    var declinedFlags = 0;
    $("td > a:contains('declined')").parent().prev().each(function () {
        declinedFlags += parseInt($(this).text().replace(",",""));
    });

    if (helpfulFlags > 0) {

        var percentHelpful = Number(Math.round((helpfulFlags / (helpfulFlags + declinedFlags)) * 100 + 'e2') + 'e-2');

        if (percentHelpful > 100 ) {
            percentHelpful = 100;
        }

        var percentColor;
        if (percentHelpful >= 90) {
            percentColor = "limegreen";
        } else if (percentHelpful >= 80) {
            percentColor = "darkorange";
        } else if (percentHelpful < 80) {
            percentColor = "red";
        } 

        var css = "<style>\
                    #progress {\
                        background: #ccc;\
                        height: 10px;\
                        width: 220px;\
                        margin: 6px 10px 10px 0;\
                        padding: 0px;\
                   }\
                    #progress:after {\
                        content: '';\
                        display: block;\
                        background: " + percentColor + ";\
                        width: " + percentHelpful + "%;\
                        height: 100%;\
                    }\
                    #percentHelpful {\
                        margin-bottom: 5px;\
                    }\
                    </style>";

        $('head').append(css);

        $("#flag-stat-info-table").before("<h3 id='percentHelpful' title='pending, aged away and disputed flags are not counted'><span id='percent'>" + percentHelpful + "%</span> helpful</h3>");
        $("span#percent").css("color", percentColor);

        $("#percentHelpful").after("<div id='progress'></div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a very high [helpful rate](http://i.imgur.com/i4KhqQP.png) ;) But it is correct on meta.

Comment: I should've posted to Code Review first :)

Comment: Or [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/)?

Comment: Flagged for migration.  ;)

Comment: @IKavanagh Yeah, it's been implemented into [SE Additional Optional Features](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/36691) but this is an actual feature request.

Comment: Along with some guide as to what percentage most users have.  I think we should be aiming for something much stricter than a usual 90/80/70/60 scale.

Comment: @Teepeemm, the problem with comparing to "most users" is that "most users" can't flag or flag very little.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I'm not sure what the scale should really be.  But you (and I, FWIW) are above 97%, and are well over 90%.  If someone is only getting 90%, should that be in the same category?  I don't consider myself to be an exceptional flagger.  This makes me wonder that if someone is only getting 75%, should they be flagging at all?  (Is there a cutoff for "this many declined leads to a flag ban"?)

Comment: Rate limit at that low of a percentage maybe (if over n total flags), but a full on ban puts you into a situation you can't recover from. flags, unlike posts, can't be improved.

Comment: @Teepeemm, I get what you're saying and I agree, but this is about displaying the percentage, not acting on it :) Just don't want to get off-topic.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209065/clarify-flagging-history-stats?

Comment: I got a bunch of errors (190) when I pasted the code into Atom with a JS linter. Is this because I don't have JQuery installed?

Comment: @CalebKleveter Yes. Some of the errors are valid, I forgot some spaces, ect... See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18251445/1454538) though.

Comment: FWIW I think my short term average was somewhere around 70-80% a few years ago when I got prodded by a moderator for having gotten too trigger happy; so that level should be colored as a warning at least.

Comment: so.. basically just: `percentHelpful = helpfulFlags / (helpfulFlags + declinedFlags) * 100` (ditching totalFlags, pendingFlags, agedFlags and disputedFlags) ?

Comment: Kind of unfair, only 18 flags aged away. That's about 10% of your overall flags. I have a third of my flags aged away. Maybe I should only flag obvious things...

Comment: @usr1234567 I flag mostly from the review queue and a lot of my flags are handled within an hour or two.   Off-topic -- I wrote another userscript that appends the time a flag was handled to the *outcome*, I like seeing stats like that. :)

Comment: How can I use this script to get my flagging percentage?

Comment: @HelpingHands Simplest way. 1. Copy the script 2. Go to your [flags page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4213132) 3. Open [console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) 4. Paste code 5. Click enter 6. Enjoy and teach others

Comment: @BhargavRao - Excellent , I got 91.52% helpful :) . Thanks for quick direction.

Comment: Why do you use `Number(n + 'e-2')` instead of `n/1e2`? And personally I would use unary `+` instead of `parseInt`.

Comment: I think it's an attempt or solution (not sure yet) to either increase precision and/or work around floating-point limitation/behavior. Personally I was contemplating: `percentHelpful=(Math.round(helpfulFlags*1e4/(helpfulFlags + declinedFlags))/100).toFixed(2)` (which should give a useful max range of `floor((2^53)/10000)===900719925474`). That should keep the math in integers for 2 decimal digits, rounded and append up to 2 zero's using toFixed.

Comment: @GitaarLAB Using strings instead of numbers can increase precision. But if you convert it back to a number in order to round or compare numerically, then it's useless.

Comment: @Oriol: thanks for that explanation. Might I politely ask/verify: is my proposed method indeed 'better'? It (ab)uses the fact that in javascript `(3/10) === 0.3` (whereas `(0.1+0.2) !== 0.3`)

Comment: @GitaarLAB Do you mean dividing after rounding? Yes, operations with integers shouldn't have floating point errors. But either use `+num.toFixed(2)` or `Math.round(num*1e2)/1e2`, no need to mix them.

Comment: thx for confirming. Indeed: `.toFixed(2)` was only intended to use for string-output to pad zero's (`0.3` becomes `'0.30'`). So int-value `percentHelpful` becomes `percentHelpful=Math.round(helpfulFlags*1e4/(helpfulFlags + declinedFlags));` followed by comparisons `if(percentHelpfull >= 90e2)` (etc.) and finally string-output: `(percentHelpful/100).toFixed(2)`

Comment: This is broken as of today, because the layout changed... Fixed version here: https://github.com/Floern/stackoverflow/blob/master/userscripts/helpful_flag_percentage.user.js

Comment: @Floern Worked thanks for that got 93.19% helpful

Comment: How about retracted flags?

Comment: @user16217248 The script is posted above, you are more than welcome to modify to your needs.