# Broken CSS in the flag history page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-history

A couple of hours ago, I noticed the CSS was updated and since then, the CSS on the flag history page is broken: the text "Your flagging history" appears on 2 lines.

[image]

This also happens on Meta.SO. However, it doesn't happen on my other account at CodeReview:

[image]

So it looks like it's specific to Stack Overflow.

For those wondering, I have the [Overall Percentage of Helpful Flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310881/1743880) user-script installed but it isn't interfering here (others have reproduced the problem without it).

I'm using Firefox 44.0.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Can reproduce: http://i.stack.imgur.com/p9FQC.png

Comment: Can reproduce in Chrome 44.0.2403.157

Comment: @Tunaki  I see you're still using the UserScript I wrote. If you're interested, I wrote a different one that breaks down the percentages for all the flag types. https://stackapps.com/questions/6773/flagging-percentages

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Didn't know about that one. Will check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah yes. This problem stemmed from `div.user-info` box not recognizing child floats. This issue has been fixed now.

Comment: Kudos. You CSS guys are damn fast. The chat team [needs](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316721/4099593) some lessons from you guys.