# Where can I find a map of programming language popularity on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Where is it possible to see a map of programming language popularity on Stack Overflow?

Ideally I want to see the top programming languages and on a map be able to determine the most popular language for that country or state.

Comment: @Maroun Nope, I've seen a few other posts similar to this. But they usually start of with a question, something like "Where can I find a map .... <more blah blah> ... I've done this <proper stuff>". (A similar post [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310881/overall-percentage-of-helpful-flags))

Comment: @BhargavRao Then it's maybe a better idea to post a question and an answer in the same time.

Comment: Yeah @Maroun, That'd be nice. But usually people just add both in the same place. So I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: If you just give some indication as to the kind of feedback you'd like from folks, I think this is fine as it is. That way folks know how to 'answer' it.

Comment: Hows this? I changed it to ask a question and then answer it myself.

Comment: @DMozzy The question is interesting, and is related to Stack Overflow. The answer answers that, ++ buddy.

Comment: @MarounMaroun How would this question *not* be on-topic for Meta.SO? It's asking about a specific aspect of the site (namely, programming language tags?) so it's most definitely on-topic.

Comment: @cybermonkey the original post wasn't a question. Check the edit history.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Gotchya. Maybe [SA.SE](http://stackapps.com/) would've been a better place?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I've made a visualization of popularity of the top programming languages on Stack Overflow.

The popularity is calculated as the question score and the answer score per person. The person is then allocated to a geographic state or country.

You can see the visualisation here: http://soversus.com.

Comment: How are people allocated to a state or country given that most people don't fill that information in, and when they do its free text so they could put anything. Did they mean Paris France or Paris Texas if they didn't say so for instance?

Comment: What would be nice would be to have numbers next to the list of languages, and to have that list sorted. Numbers are easier to read than a pie chart (at least to me).

Comment: Re: @RobertLongson. I take what the user had put in and query a webservice provided by GeoNames: http://www.geonames.org.  Its crude but does seem to give an ok result where people haven't been too crazy.

Comment: Re: @Denys Séguret let me see what I can do.

Comment: hmmm HTML and Java are big in Antartica.

Comment: What does the domain mean?

Comment: Also I would love to see the Perl programming language. Our popularity is growing again and while we don't see as much traffic as PHP or C there is a steady stream of questions and a very active community.

Comment: Its for StackOverflow Versus. The idea was you could do Java versus C#, Python vs Ruby etc.

Comment: Looks more like "Let's make America C# again". I'm very sad to see how low the numbers are for C++ everywhere in the US—except for New Mexico, that is. Even in Illinois, where C++ is the "winner", it is by a very small margin.

Comment: The top languages are sourced from here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags . In the future I might add more languages and options.

Comment: SoVersus, like Universus but restricted to SO-ers. Nice. Awesome visualization.

Comment: @Giuseppe I like that explanation better :)

Comment: Greenland appears to be a bit biased towards Java

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd - Yeah there is not a lot of data for it. Anything under 100 points gets filtered out, which leaves Greenland with only Java.

Comment: If I may praise for an histogram instead of pie char: http://andrewg-crabtreeanalytics.blogspot.fr/2012/05/are-pie-charts-evil-or-just.html

Comment: Could you please add Swift too? Must be in the top... :)

Comment: The data analysis is very interesting. One thing I would note, however, is that PHP is likely to be more popular than is shown here, as a lot of PHP dev work is done within WordPress, Drupal and Joomla, all of which have their own separate sites in the SE network. There are a lot of other SE technology sites, so other languages may also see a similar effect, but I suspect it's most pronounced for PHP as those three CMS platforms make up a significant chunk of the whole web, let alone of PHP development.

Comment: How can you base this on votes? Seems like nonsense. If there are for example 100 bad "x language" programmers living in country A and one single good "x language" programmer living in country B, then "x languages" is more popular in country B if that single programmer managed to gather more rep than the 100 bad ones (who only visit SO briefly, since they are mostly busy programming).

Comment: A much better metric would simply be the number of questions and answers posted by unique users.

Comment: I'm unsure if this truly reflects popularity though. I asked a lot of questions on Java but I hate it with all my heart.